# Autonumber rows in select SQL based on column changes

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

I use a select all statement to retrieve all values from table A. Table A sample is the following:

```
+---+----+---+
| a | 23 | X | 
+---+----+---+
| a | 23 | Y |
+---+----+---+
| a | 24 | X |
+---+----+---+
| a | 24 | Y |
+---+----+---+
| b | 24 | X |
+---+----+---+
| b | 24 | Y |
+---+----+---+
| b | 25 | X |
+---+----+---+
| b | 25 | Y |
+---+----+---+
| b | 25 | Z | 
+---+----+---+
```

For purposes in later stadium of this query, I would like to have a record number for each unique combination of column 1 and 2. For example:

```
+---+----+---+---+
| a | 23 | X | 1 |
+---+----+---+---+
| a | 23 | Y | 2 |
+---+----+---+---+
| a | 24 | X | 1 |
+---+----+---+---+
| a | 24 | Y | 2 |
+---+----+---+---+
| b | 24 | X | 1 |
+---+----+---+---+
| b | 24 | Y | 2 |
+---+----+---+---+
| b | 25 | X | 1 |
+---+----+---+---+
| b | 25 | Y | 2 |
+---+----+---+---+
| b | 25 | Z | 3 |
+---+----+---+---+
```

Is this possible to do with SQL and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of your problem would use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by col1, col2)
from t;
```

Your sample data suggests `dense_rank()` with `partitition by`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) as seqnum
from t;
```

Comment: i think you just edited you answer while i was testing it. Turned out that select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) as seqnum from t was the answer to what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is

```
SELECT Distinct  
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1 ASC,Col2 ASC) AS Row_num,
  Col1, Col2
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Sorry, I provided wrong sample table. Is this now still applicable?